# SQL query to match Lego design with pieces and quantity of pieces

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the fastest/less complicated way to get a result for the following problem.

I have a DB of (for example) Lego Kits, where each Kit has a description and a list of Lego pieces needed and how many of them. An user can insert his collection of Lego pieces and then ask what Kit he can build with his pieces and what else he can build if he buys other pieces (maybe a first limit is that he can buy only 1 type of piece).

What I have is roughly this:

```
LegoDesign
- id
- name

LegoBlock
- id
- type
- weight
- description

LegoBlockForDesign
- LegoDesign.id
- LegoBlock.id
- numberOfPiecesNeeded

Collection
(- User.id)
- LegoBlock.id
- quantityAvailable
```

For example, the DB contains the LegoDesign for StarWar's Death Star. LegoBlock contains a long list of pieces like "2x2 black square" or "small wheel" etc. LegoBlockForDesign assign the LegoBlocks to the LegoDesign of he Death Star (for example 1000 pieces of "2x2 black square"). 
The Table collection instead contains what pieces the user has.
Now the problem here is that I have to query for the Design with the pieces the user has which means 1st checking for the LegoBlock.id and then checking for the numberOfPiecesNeeded since I could have some 2x2 black square pieces but not enough to build the Death Star. This is the first query. The second one should check for Design that contains the block I have plus some blocks I don't have in my collection. This means that I should check for LegoBlock in my possession but with less than the right amount and for Design with blocks not in my possession. The latter needs a limit that could be set manually. I was thinking to let the user pick between a limit on the number of pieces to buy (ie max 30 pieces) or a limit on difficulty of pieces (ie. no "special block" to buy, like some special wheel or character present only in specific Design (the characters of Star Wars, for example)).

I'm not entirely sure it can be done in SQL, especially because I have to check for quantities and not only for the existence of the block.

EDIT:
I've added LegoBlock.type and LegoBlock.weight. This way I can define type = common,rare,unique to define normal pieces or specific ones (like the Star Wars characters that can be defined rare. I don't want to buy those pieces since they can be used only on the StarWars' Design). Weight instead can be used to give a priority (I like blue, so I would prefer to see the Design where I have to buy blue pieces).

Comment: awful choice of names :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query... This will give you the LegoDesigns in which the user has all of the blocks and quantity of blocks for:

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.name
FROM
    Collection a
INNER JOIN
    LegoBlockForDesign b ON 
        a.LegoBlock.id = b.LegoBlock.id AND
        a.quantityAvailable >= b.numberOfPiecesNeeded
INNER JOIN
    LegoDesign c ON b.LegoDesign.id = c.id
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT LegoDesign.id, COUNT(1) AS totalneeded
        FROM LegoBlockForDesign
        GROUP BY LegoDesign.id
    ) d ON c.id = d.LegoDesign.id
WHERE
    a.User.id = <userid here>
GROUP BY
    c.id, c.name, d.totalneeded
HAVING 
    COUNT(1) = d.totalneeded
```

**Edit 2:** This query will retrieve all designs the user can build given their current collection plus additional lego blocks that are selected by the user looking to purchase them:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            c.id, c.name, NULL AS notInCollection
        FROM
            Collection a
        INNER JOIN
            LegoBlockForDesign b ON a.LegoBlock.id = b.LegoBlock.id
        INNER JOIN
            LegoDesign c ON b.LegoDesign.id = c.id
        WHERE
            a.quantityAvailable >= b.numberOfPiecesNeeded AND
            a.User.id = <userid here>
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            d.id, d.name, 1 AS notInCollection
        FROM
            LegoDesign d
        INNER JOIN
            LegoBlockForDesign e ON d.id = e.LegoDesign.id
        WHERE
            e.LegoBlock.id IN (<comma sepd list of legoblockids here>)
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT LegoDesign.id, COUNT(1) AS totalneeded
        FROM LegoBlockForDesign
        GROUP BY LegoDesign.id
    ) b ON a.id = b.LegoDesign.id
GROUP BY 
    a.id, a.name, b.totalneeded
HAVING 
    COUNT(1) = b.totalneeded AND 
    COUNT(a.notInCollection) > 0
```

The `UNION ALL` basically tacks on rows representing designs that contain those particular selected blocks so that the `HAVING COUNT(*)` on the outside can take them into account. The `notInCollection` field in the FROM subselect is a flag indicating if the part is already in the user's collection or not... so `HAVING COUNT(f.notInCollection) > 0` excludes designs which the user already has all the parts for in his/her collection. This is much more efficient than doing a `NOT IN (<1st query as subquery>)` which you could also do.

The query assumes that the user is previously presented and can only select from a list of legoblocks which he/she doesn't already have, or else there will be duplication in the UNION which will throw off the results.

You can also put in a list of legoblockids so users can select more than one legoblock to see the increasing number of designs they can build as they select more blocks.

Comment: See my answer on Raphaël's answer. I already thought something like your second query (but admittedly not written down, I didn't know COALESCE). The problem there is that it will show you all the Design. What I need is to show only a limited number of Design that I can't immediately build but where I need to buy a limited amount of pieces. As I said above, the limit will be done outside the query probably, even if I should probably add a category and a weight to the block types.

Comment: Okay, I think see what you need... so given the current user's collection, retrieve the designs the user *CAN* build *IF* the user purchases such and such piece, excluding all designs for which the user can already build.

My question is when users filter by block, will they also be specifying the quantity they wish to purchase? ...Or will users only select the block, and the query will tell how many pieces are required of that block?

This query will take some more thought, but I believe it can be done.

Comment: The design the user can build with the pieces he owns it's easy, so you are right. For your question I think the user should not specify the quantity, but only the block (type,weight etc). I am of the opinion that the quantity doesn't matter once you know you can buy that piece.Raphaël spoke about the price and that could be a filter BUT I think it will complicate things because the prices cannot be on the DB and must be on the user table(s).

Comment: I'm testing right now the first query and it appears to either have stuck or be very slow.Minutes slow

Comment: @mobinoob, I just optimized both of my solutions to use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a subquery in `HAVING`, so it should be quicker as the result of the join only needs to execute once, whereas the subquery will execute on every iteration. Let me know how the modified solutions perform.

Comment: I am now using only the first example and it works perfectly, thanks! I am not using real quantities, I just set 0 on both coll and designs. I also added index on my LBFD table where I forgot :( I suppose the indexes where the major boost for speed. I still have to study how to implement the second part, but that's after I find a way to get exact values for the quantities/blocks I crawl.

Comment: My fault:( I did a wrong copy and paste so I tested TWICE your FIRST solution and it's apparently 4 time faster than the new one. I'm also having difficulties understanding it

Answer (score 2):

**First Query.** 
This will give you the block name, and difference between the pieces needed and the pieces that the user have BY LegoBlock type (0 if user has enough or more than needed).

This can be used as a subquery, if you don't want all the details

```
select lbd.legoBlock_id, lb.Description, Greatest(lbd.NumberOfPiecesNeeded - Coalesce(c.quantityAvailable, 0), 0)
from legoBlockForDesign lbd
inner join LegoBlock lb on lb.Id = lbd.LegoBlock_id

left join Collection c on c.legoBlock_id = lbd.legoBlock_id
where lbd.LegoDesign_id = <the design id queried>
and c.User_Id = <the user id queried>
-- if you want only the blocks with missing quantity
--and Greatest(lbd.NumberOfPiecesNeeded - Coalesce(c.quantityAvailable, 0), 0) > 0
```

The second query is hard to answer, as I don't know which filters you wanna use ("special block" doesn't appear in the model, I presume it's in LegoBlock table, just confirm).
And what means the "number of pieces missing" ? Is it global ( 30 = 15 2*2 + 10 3*1 + 5 125*3) ?

Well, with the quantity filter, you could do something like that

**Second query**

```
select ld.Id, ld.Description, Sum(Greatest(lbd.NumberOfPiecesNeeded - Coalesce(c.quantityAvailable, 0), 0)) missingPieces
from legoDesign ld
inner join LegoBlockDesign lbd on lbd.LegoDesign_Id = ld.Id
inner join LegoBlock lb on lb.Id = lbd.LegoBlock_id
left join Collection c on c.legoBlock_id = lbd.legoBlock_id
where c.User_Id = <the user id queried>
group by ld.Id, ld.Description
--Filter on quantity
-- having Sum(Greatest(lbd.NumberOfPiecesNeeded - Coalesce(c.quantityAvailable, 0), 0))<=30
--ORDER BY the "less missing pieces"
--ORDER BY Sum(Greatest(lbd.NumberOfPiecesNeeded - Coalesce(c.quantityAvailable, 0)
```

Comment: I don't have a precise answer about the second query. If you have 10000 design you don't expect to see 20 design that you can build and the other 9980 listed with the pieces you miss. What could be done is a filter outside the SQL query to define limits. I could have a list of LegoBlock.id or eventually add a LegoBlock.category like "common","hardToFind","unique". I suppose I can also "weight" the pieces so that I get results for the more important missing blocks (ie. I like square blocks, so show me the design where i need to buy square blocks only)

Comment: Sure. My remark was just that the proposed db structure did not match some of the proposed filters. I could also imagine a filter on "price" , which would be easy to put in the second query I gave. Just need to add a "Price" field in LegoBlock table.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the "piece missing" is referred to single pieces, not global. Red 2x2 Block total:200, your possession 120, missing 80. Red 4x2 Block total: 10, your possession 9, missing 1. Total isn't really useful, while the total price could be. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: That what the first query does. If you wanna do this in second query, you can add  add lb.Id, lb.Description in the select clause, and also add them in the group by. This will group results (and sums of "missing") by lego block for each design

Comment: sorry for answering late, but I had to rebuild the DB and I still don't have a set of test data. I think the second query might be useful for me, while the first not since it specifies a design id, while I'd like to have something like "Select all designs where my_collection contains design.pieces" :) This is a long query, especially if I have more than 100000 designs. I will find a way to limit it later. (note that I didn't mention the quantity on this comment, just for the sake of semplicity.I'm in fact trying without considering it first)

Answer (score 0):

First Query - By looking at design after which 0 or more blocks are remaining for blocks used in that design, we can get the design which user can build from his collection.

```
  select design 
  from    (select lb.*, ld.id ,lbfd.numberOfPiecesNeeded numberOfPiecesNeeded,
                  ld.name design 
           from LegoDesign ld, LegoBlock lb ,LegoBlockForDesign lbfd 
           where ld.id=lbfd.id 
           and lb.id=lbfd.lbid ) a 
  left outer join Collection coll
        on coll.legoblock_id = a.legoblock_id 
        and coll.user_id=`<USER_ID> `
  group by a.legodesign_id 
  having min(coalesce(coll.quantityAvailable,0)-a.numberOfPiecesNeeded)>=0;
```

For the second query changing the `having` clause like this `sum(a.numberOfPiecesNeeded-coalesce(coll.quantityAvailable,0)) between 1 and x` will give the design where we x no of pieces at max required to complete the design. This data can we joined with LegoBlockForDesign and Legoblock in same query to get the each individual block count